# facebook graph search no results

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using the API console .

This GET request no results:

```
search?type=page&q=java
```

It returns

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I saw older blog posts written in 2016 and prior. -- They have results.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

Comment: @CBroe How do i search for users then? Impossible?

Comment: yes, impossible. although, your question was about searching for pages, which is impossible too.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

> You can no longer use the /search endpoint with the following object
>   types:
>
> - event
> - group
> - page
> - user

Edit: There is a new endpoint for Pages now: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/searching

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/searching - Pages searching is indeed working now

Comment: thanx, that seems to be new. i will add it to my answer.